# WPF TextBox not displaying validation error message

Tags: wpf, textbox, staticresource, validationrules, multidatatrigger

I have bound a validation rule to my WPF TextBox in order to control what user types in.

**WPF TextBox**:

```
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.Row="1" 
             IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}"                                 
             Margin="5,8,8,5">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="ReferenceId"
                     UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                     ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <vRules:RefValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>                         
        </TextBox.Text>            
    </TextBox>
```

It works fine. When user types in something wrong, TextBox border is getting red warning user that the input is incorrect.

Furthermore, now I am trying to display the validation error message under the TextBox as well, so I bind to the TextBox below static resource:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="ValidationTextBoxErrorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"> 
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="True" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>                                    
                                    <StackPanel>                                        
                                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="placeholder" />
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="11" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}" />
                                    </StackPanel>                                    
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And the TextBox now looks like below:

```
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.Row="1"
             Style="{StaticResource ValidationTextBoxErrorStyle}"
             IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}"                                 
             Margin="5,8,8,5">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="ReferenceId"
                     UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                     ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <vRules:RefValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>                         
        </TextBox.Text>            
    </TextBox>
```

Now when running it, if user types in a wrong reference Id in the TextBox with an invalid format, the validation error message is correctly displayed under the TextBox, but now the TextBox border is not getting red.

So I would like both things, I mean, when value for TextBox is invalid, I want TextBox border to get RED and at the same time, to display the validation error message under it.

So, What am I doing wrong?

Note that I want TextBox to get RED and display the validation error message under it, if and only if, there is a validation error and IsEnabled property is true so as there is more than one condition I have used a MultiDataTrigger.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `Border` to the `ControlTemplate`:

```
<Style x:Key="ValidationTextBoxErrorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}" Value="True" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="True" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="placeholder" />
                            </Border>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="11" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: @Ralph: Please remember to accept the answer if your original issue has been solved.